# Proper way of casting for a method reference parameter

Tags: c++, casting, reference, parameter-passing

I have an array of objects stored. I want to reach them. The below code works just fine:

```
class Primitive
{
public:
    int SomePrimitiveValue = 5;
};

class Derived : public Primitive
{
public:
    int SomeDerivedValue = 8;
};

Primitive * ExtractTheLast()
{
    if (FCount > 0)
    {
        Primitive * result = *((Primitive**)((char*)FData + (FCount - 1 * TypeSize())));
        RemoveByIndex(FCount - 1);
        return result;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    Derived * result = (Derived *)ExtractTheLast();
    if (!result)
        result = new Derived();
}
```

but I want to see if this access operation `ExtractTheLast` is successful so I modified the code such as;

```
bool ExtractTheLast(Primitive *& lastItem)
{
    if (FCount > 0)
    {
        lastItem = *((Primitive**)((char*)FData + (FCount - 1 * TypeSize())));
        RemoveByIndex(FCount - 1);
        return true;
    }
    lastItem = nullptr;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Derived * result = nullptr;
    if (!ExtractTheLast((Primitive*&)result))
        result = new Derived();
}
```

In this code `ExtractTheLast((Primitive*&)result)` doesn't worked as I intended, my guess is compiler converting or maybe treating the content data of the class as it is `Primitive` and returns a broken object.

My question is how can I properly type cast inside a method's parameter zone? and I really don't want to use templates like `ExtractTheLast<Derived>()`.

**-------------------EDIT---------------------**

After i realized my question is not clear enough, i try to summerize it but couldn't create the same result as in my project so i decided showing two way which first one works but the second one gives funny resluts.

Please bare in mind that i only want to know the difference between those two line of codes
 `(RenderRequestO *)Requests_idle->GetTheLast()`

and

`Requests_idle->GetTheLast((PrimitiveO*&)result)`

one of them returns the object directly and other one returns it as parameter and i think when i try to type cast inside the parameter block, compiler gives wrong result.

this is the code works fine:

```
    MutexLock(mutex);
    RenderRequestO * result = Requests_idle->Count() > 0 ? (RenderRequestO *)Requests_idle->GetTheLast() : new RenderRequestO();
    if (Requests_idle->Count() > 0)
        Requests_idle->RemoveLast();
...
..
```

and this is the code doesn't work as i want it to be:

```
    MutexLock(mutex);
    RenderRequestO * result = nullptr;
    if (!Requests_idle->GetTheLast((PrimitiveO*&)result))
        result = new RenderRequestO();
...
..
```

if i get the related object such as `(RenderRequestO *)Requests_idle->GetTheLast()` it works fine but if i get try to get it like `Requests_idle->GetTheLast((PrimitiveO*&)result)` it returns an object but its derived fields are all inaccessable (when i move my mouse over it intellisense says "unable to read memory")

Comment: Anytime you need to use C-style casting, that's a red flag that your most likely doing something wrong. And please create a [mcve] to show us, what is `FCount`? What is `FData`? It seems like you're breaking a lot of strict aliasing rules and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `*((Primitive**)((char*)` That look extremely suspicious. 95% chance this is just wrong

Comment: ok i guess you guys are right, i am summerizing my question, and i will edit it so it gets the point, sory for confusion

Comment: As a first step: Instead of doing C-style casts like `(RenderRequestO*)something`, use `static_cast<RenderRequestO*>(something)`. If the compiler complains when you do that, then you are usually doing something illegal in the original version. You also still need to provide us the definitions of several things that are important, for example what `PrimitiveO` or `RenderRequestO` is (all part of why we ask for a [mcve]). If you can extract a representative piece of code that compiles without errors on https://godbolt.org, then you're almost guaranteed to get a good answer here.

Comment: i can static type cast `RenderRequestO * result = static_cast<RenderRequestO*>(Requests_idle->GetTheLast());` like that but how can i static type cast inside parameter block `Requests_idle->GetTheLast(static_cast<RenderRequestO*>(result))`

Comment: its tonnes of codes and moving it to godbolt.org would take forever.. maybe i should ask it like this: in  c# lets say we have a list which contains objects and i want to get an item by index, i would write my method such as `bool List.Get(int index, ref Primitive obj)` .. what is the equavelent in c++

Comment: The main problem here is that your `ExtractTheLast` only promises to extract a `Primitive`, but you want to have a `Derived`. If `ExtractTheLast` always yields a `Derived`, why not use that in the signature? If it does not, then it doesn't make sense (read: is illegal) to try and put the result into a `Derived`.

Comment: yes you are right, i usualy do what you said, but since i am sure that it will give me a Derived (that i only store derived ones) and it looks more readable, i wanted to use it like that but even in c# that might not be possible.. maybe i should remove (delete) this question all together :(
sory for wasting your time

Comment: We all learn :) For the record, this would've been a good code sample to use in the question: https://godbolt.org/z/A5F5ZA

Comment: thank you Max. As a result: compiler lets you use it like that: `ExtractTheLast((Primitive*&)result)` but it is a wrong execution.. that what i learnt :)